# Cant resolve DNS Domain with ipv6

Tags: active-directory, ipv6, windows-server-2022

I have 2 virtual servers with Windows Server 2022 and Windows 11 client. When i create de Active Directory's domain and set the static IP on ipv6 (i cant do with ipv4, ipv6 is mandatory), dont resolve name, but the name host and the ipv6. I installed the Active Directory according tutorials of microsoft. I aplicate `nslookup` and this is the message:

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Servidor predeterminado:  UnKnown
Address:  fc00::cafe:218:1
```

the ipconfig was:

```
 Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
   Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection #2
   Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-41-DF-2D
   DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sí
   Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
   Dirección IPv6 . . . . . . . . . . : fc00::cafe:218:1(Preferido)
   Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::50d9:9a9c:6f2e:d7e7%5(Preferido)
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . :
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 167775273
   DUID de cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2A-CF-8C-BA-00-0C-29-41-DF-23
   Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : fc00::cafe:218:1
   NetBIOS sobre TCP/IP. . . . . . . . . . . : deshabilitado
```

thats my get-adddomaincontroller on powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrador.DC1.000>  Get-ADDomainController -Identity "DC1" | Select-Object Name, Domain

Name Domain
---- ------
DC1  asir218.priv
```

dc1 is my computer name. When i do ping to the machine name, only ping to internal ipv6

Comment: And the DC config?

Comment: is the standard. no OU, users , etc. no dns installed previously

Comment: The `fc00::cafe:218:1` address in in a reserved range that you should not use. The ULA range is `fc00::/7`, but the first half of the range (`fc00::/8`) is reserved for a global authority to assign. The second half of the range (`fd00::/8`) is available to be locally assigned, but the next 40 bits must be randomly chosen, giving you a `/48` prefix from which you can get 65,536 standard `/64` networks. (see _[RFC 4193, Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193)_.)

Comment: after all it was a bug from Windows Server, but thanks! Now i have DNS on ipv6